# Is it possible to use multiple hovers on a single object in html?

Tags: html, css, hover

Can you use multiple :hover selectors?
What I want to achieve is a rainbow background for a button when I hover over it and for it to loop with a transition. Is there anything I could use to achieve something like that? I know how to transition but not to loop or/and achieve the rainbow effect.
Does there exist something like hover1, 2 etc.? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried? What happened? Please see [ask] and show us a specific case.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to have multiple `:hover`. BUT, there are other approaches to do the same as you want.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129332/css-for-creating-animated-gradient-button-background/51138134) as an example for this.

About those pseudo-elements, [this is a good answer to check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11999197/10473393)

Comment: Don't link to other answers. Flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Agreed! I followed this approach because while his answer isn't possible (And this would be a duplicate), there is a different way to solve his problem. Just tried to help xD

Comment: Then use the comment option instead!

Comment: It's still what I was looking for. Thanks! 